# Axios cors issue with Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3, laravel-socialite

When i use mounted in **Vue3** everthing works. But using @click gives me an error. When i click the button fasts before the page loaded everything it returns json which should be expected.

Error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/redirect' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-socket-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
socialiteLogin(provider) {
    axios({
         method: "GET",
         headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
         },
         withCredentials: false,
         url: `/auth/${provider}/redirect`,
   })
     .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
     });
},
```

Comment: 1. AFAIK, I believe it should be `withCredentials: true` especially if you are using jwt tokens inside cookies with HttpOnly setup. 2, check cors policy in your laravel. or proxy settings in your vue?

Comment: i dont think it is laravel issue because the axios request work when i run it from mounted.  this function is used in login page where token should not be exist because it is only about to login.

Comment: got it.. so the problem is only in this route? As for other routes, you can do post request without issues? Did I understood it correctly?